# How to put NIS (new israeli shekel) in code?

Tags: c#

I have simple integer that i want to convert into `NIS`, so ifound this:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20aa/index.htm

Whats mean this `(U+20AA)` and how can i use it in my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# files are Unicode, so you should be able to simply copy and paste the character into a string or character literal in your C# file.

Example:

```
char c = '₪';
// or...
string s = "₪ is a great character!";
```

You can select and copy the character from the above code.

Comment: I put it this way: .ToString("(U+20AA)")

Answer (score 2):

"\u20AA" Same way as C/C++ [2.4.1 Unicode character escape sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx)